# How come the Observer Pattern look more like a "Notifier Pattern"?

Tags: design-patterns

The Observer Pattern seems very much like a Notifier Pattern, since it is based on the subject notifying objects that are interested.  The "notify" part seems the most important, because without it, nothing gets notified.

(was there ever some thoughts to rename this pattern to the Notifier Pattern?)

Are there any Observer Patterns out there that are more "observer based"?

For example, one that has a timer so that the observers will look into the object being observed every n milliseconds.

Or one that (like in machine code), when a routine wants to observe a memory location, it calls a certain routine and says, "if memory location TEMPERATURE_VALUE (0x32FF2C12, for example) gets modified, then call me (it knows the value is modified by the hardware interrupt mechanism).  In this case, the subject doesn't notify or cannot decide whether to notify or not, but is forced to be observed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The observer pattern is so named because the objects attached to the subject object "observe" its behavior.  That the mechanism for such observance (a push of information from the subject to the observer) is initiated by the subject object does not change the inherent function of the observer objects (namely, that of observing).

The pattern might be better described as a "subscriber pattern," in that the observer objects "subscribe" to events on the subject object, and thereafter "listen" to those events.  It would be accurate to say that the observer object does not observe the subject object directly, but rather indirectly through the information provided to it through the subject object's firing of the subscribed events.

It wouldn't be the first time a pattern was misnamed.  Inversion of Control sounds really complicated until you realize that all that really means is providing needed objects (dependencies) to a class by assigning them to parameters in a constructor.  The term "Dependency Injection" was coined in an effort to make this concept clearer.

Comment: All true.  Observer is frequently called Publish/Subscribe (Pub/Sub) (though not strictly accurate), and in Java Subscribers are ActionListeners and EventListeners.  So all of those names are "observed" in the wild... :)  (Couldn't resist)

Comment: While IoC isn't the most intuitive of names, it describes what the pattern does fairly well :)

Comment: By the way, I think some books say the Observer Pattern is the same as the Pub/Sub Pattern, while some books say Observer Pattern is one to many, while Pub/Sub Pattern is many-to-one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the pattern more, I think this is the reason that it is called "The Observer Pattern":

1) any method can "notify".  The data object (the subject) can notify 3 hard-coded objects, who are acting as observers.  Or the data object can go through an dynamic array of "registered" observers and notify each of them.  The key is not about notifying.  The key is about registration.

2) We don't want to hard-code the 3 observing objects, because this is tight-coupling and therefore decrease object-reuse.  If we allow the "observer registration", then 2 objects can register and then observe the subject, or 3 objects can register and observe the subject, or any number of objects can register and observe the subject.

3) So, it is the "registration of the observers" that is the key idea of this pattern.  So it can be called "The Observer Registration Pattern", or for short, just "The Observer Pattern".